# GitHub Actions CodeQL init action failed Not Found

Tags: github-actions, codeql, nektos-act

I am trying to configure CodeQL scanning on my repo. For that purpose I am using the template provided by GitHub:

```
# For most projects, this workflow file will not need changing; you simply need
# to commit it to your repository.
#
# You may wish to alter this file to override the set of languages analyzed,
# or to provide custom queries or build logic.
#
# ******** NOTE ********
# We have attempted to detect the languages in your repository. Please check
# the `language` matrix defined below to confirm you have the correct set of
# supported CodeQL languages.
#
name: CodeQL
run-name: CodeQL
env:
  virtualMachine: ubuntu-latest
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - development
      - release/*
  pull_request:
    # The branches below must be a subset of the branches above
    branches:
      - master
      - development
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 9 * * *'
jobs:
  analyze:
    name: Analyze
    runs-on: ${{ env.virtualMachine }}
    permissions:
      actions: read
      contents: read
      security-events: write
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        language:
          - csharp
          - javascript
        # CodeQL supports [ 'cpp', 'csharp', 'go', 'java', 'javascript', 'python', 'ruby' ]
        # Use only 'java' to analyze code written in Java, Kotlin or both
        # Use only 'javascript' to analyze code written in JavaScript, TypeScript or both
        # Learn more about CodeQL language support at https://aka.ms/codeql-docs/language-support
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    # Initializes the CodeQL tools for scanning.
    - name: Initialize CodeQL
      uses: github/codeql-action/init@v2
      with:
        languages: ${{ matrix.language }}
        # If you wish to specify custom queries, you can do so here or in a config file.
        # By default, queries listed here will override any specified in a config file.
        # Prefix the list here with "+" to use these queries and those in the config file.

        # Details on CodeQL's query packs refer to : https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/configuring-code-scanning#using-queries-in-ql-packs
        # queries: security-extended,security-and-quality

    # Autobuild attempts to build any compiled languages  (C/C++, C#, Go, or Java).
    # If this step fails, then you should remove it and run the build manually (see below)
    - name: Autobuild
      uses: github/codeql-action/autobuild@v2

    # ℹ️ Command-line programs to run using the OS shell.
    #  See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun

    #   If the Autobuild fails above, remove it and uncomment the following three lines.
    #   modify them (or add more) to build your code if your project, please refer to the EXAMPLE below for guidance.

    # - run: |
    #     echo "Run, Build Application using script"
    #     ./location_of_script_within_repo/buildscript.sh

    - name: Perform CodeQL Analysis
      uses: github/codeql-action/analyze@v2
      with:
        category: "/language:${{matrix.language}}"
```

When I am trying to run it locally on my machine using nektos/act I get the following error:

> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   Start image=catthehacker/ubuntu:full-latest
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]     docker pull image=catthehacker/ubuntu:full-latest platform= username=*** forcePull=true
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]     docker create image=catthehacker/ubuntu:full-latest platform= entrypoint=["tail" "-f" "/dev/null"] cmd=[]
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]     docker run image=catthehacker/ubuntu:full-latest platform= entrypoint=["tail" "-f" "/dev/null"] cmd=[]
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   ☁  git clone 'https://github.com/github/codeql-action' # ref=v2
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   ☁  git clone 'https://github.com/github/codeql-action' # ref=v2
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   ☁  git clone 'https://github.com/github/codeql-action' # ref=v2
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   Matrix: map[language:csharp]
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1] ⭐ Run Main Checkout repository
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]     docker cp src=C:\Users\ezequiel.de-luca\NoBackUp\Cobani\Repos\cobani-content. dst=/mnt/c/Users/ezequiel.de-luca/NoBackUp/Cobani/Repos/cobani-content
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   ✅  Success - Main Checkout repository
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1] ⭐ Run Main Initialize CodeQL
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]     docker cp src=C:\Users\ezequiel.de-luca.cache\act/github-codeql-action-init@v2/ dst=/var/run/act/actions/github-codeql-action-init@v2/
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]     docker exec cmd=[node /var/run/act/actions/github-codeql-action-init@v2/lib/init-action.js] user= workdir=
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   ❗  ::error::Not Found
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   ❗  ::error::init action failed: Not Found
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   ❌  Failure - Main Initialize CodeQL
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   ⚙  ::set-env:: CODEQL_ACTION_FEATURE_SARIF_COMBINE=true
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   ⚙  ::set-env:: CODEQL_ACTION_FEATURE_WILL_UPLOAD=true
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   ⚙  ::set-env:: CODEQL_ACTION_VERSION=2.2.11
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1] exitcode '1': failure
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1] ⭐ Run Post Initialize CodeQL
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]     docker exec cmd=[node /var/run/act/actions/github-codeql-action-init@v2/lib/init-action-post.js] user= workdir=
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]     ::warning::Debugging artifacts are unavailable since the 'init' Action failed before it could produce any.
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   ✅  Success - Post Initialize CodeQL
> | (node:36) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: HttpError: Not Found
> |     at /run/act/actions/github-codeql-action-init@v2/node_modules/@octokit/request/dist-node/index.js:66:23
> |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> |     at async Job.doExecute (/run/act/actions/github-codeql-action-init@v2/node_modules/bottleneck/light.js:405:18)
> | (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> | (node:36) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
> | (node:36) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   Job failed
> Error: Job 'Analyze' failed

My understanding is that it is not finding the action github/codeql-action/init in the repo, but I do not see any error during

> [CodeQL/Analyze-1]   ☁  git clone 'https://github.com/github/codeql-action' # ref=v2

Do you know if I should configure the init differently?

Comment: The action looks cloned (see the path in the error message), this looks like a different HTTP error to me: HttpError: Not Found
| at /run/act/actions/github-codeql-action-init@v2/node_modules/@octokit/request/dist-node/index.js:66:23 --- it does not tell which URL thought. Makes more sense?

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/github/codeql-action/issues/967

Answer (score 0):

According to this relevant GitHub issue (https://github.com/github/codeql-action/issues/967)'s [comment](https://github.com/github/codeql-action/issues/967#issuecomment-1061265953):

> ... The codeql-action will not work as a local action through `act`. The failure is because the workflow is making a request to determine what its `run_id` is and since this is being run through `act`, there is no workflow run.

I tried this [suggestion](https://github.com/github/codeql-action/issues/967#issuecomment-1089244559) about passing `GITHUB_RUN_ID` with a recent workflow run ID:

```bash
act -s GITHUB_TOKEN=[PAT] --env GITHUB_RUN_ID=[RECENT_RUN_ID]
```

but that didn't work for me.